# Unwanted scroll bar fading in at top of browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have an html page which is behaving strangely when I click on a link in the navigation bar. When I click on one of the links on the right side of the page, I get taken to the appropriate place in the page, but a scroll fades in at the top of the page, then disappears. How do I stop it from happening?

Here is the live page where it is happening: [sixhens.com](http://sixhens.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a minus margin of `-15px` on `.navbar-right` that causes the width to overlap the parent `.container` div.

If you reset the minus margin, the navbar won't overlap the container, and you won't see the scrollbar:

```
 .navbar-right {
   margin-right:0; 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks very much Tony. I tried your fix, but sadly it didnt work. I altered it to `margin-right:0;` instead of `margin-left:0;` and that seem to work - is this what you meant? I am curious though as to why this is happening - `.navbar-right` is set in `bootstrap.min.css`, I suspect that I have messed something up in my css.

Comment: @Adam you're welcome - yes sorry I meant right instead of left :)